# convert unix timestamp to date of new field in mongodb chart

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to add a new field `ts` in charts in mongodb as follows:

```
{$toDate: {$multiply : ['$date', 1000]}}
```

Values for `'$date'` are for example `1631023883000`.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I get chart like this:

[image]

So calculated values are like: Jan-53663, May 53660.

What is wrong?

Comment: Simply try `{$toDate: '$date'}`